# Amazon Web Services new instance

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS and need to learn how to use Cloudformation with JSON to setup an ECB the will run a Python app on the web.

Could someone point me to some good JSON examples?

I need to setup an ALB as well with a VPN.

I hope that's not too much for a beginner.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Asking questions to recommend off-site resources is considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you can learn more about what this site is about.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link [ymal examples of cloud formation template](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/aws/roll-vpn-aws-cloudformation-part-one/). I personally feel that yaml is better in terms of visibility than json(just my personal thought :)). In case you feel more comfortable with json. You can use yaml to json converter.

Answer (score 0):

The authors of "AWS in Action" maintain a good collection of templates for basic infrastructure:

https://templates.cloudonaut.io/en/stable/

Also AWS has a startup kit:

https://github.com/aws-samples/startup-kit-templates